# Rotate model in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Hi I am developing an application using the viewer api. I have a master model. And I load other models on this model. I can move and resize these models that I have uploaded later. I achieved rotation using makeRotationX ,makeRotationY,makeRotationZ functions. But when I rotate the loaded model, it moves it to the starting point. What could be the reason for this? So for example, I add the cube to the left, but it moves to the main 0,0,0 point and does the rotation.
[image: first]

I just change the rotation Y value and this is the result.
[image: second]

Code :

```
cubeModel.getModelTransform().makeRotationY(inputValue * Math.PI / 180);
                viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the model's `THREE.Matrix4` transform that you retrieve using `model.getModelTransform()` may already include some transformation (in this particular case, the transformation is offsetting the red cube to the left). And the `makeRotationY` method doesn't **append** any transformation, it simply resets the matrix to a new transformation that only rotates around the Y axis.

Instead, what you'll want to do is something like this:

```js
let xform = model.getModelTransform().clone();
// modify the xform instead of resetting it, for example
let rotate = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(0.1);
let scale = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(0.1, 0.5, 0.1);
xform.premultiply(rotate);
xform.multiply(scale);
// since we cloned the matrix earlier (good practice), apply it back to the model
model.setModelTransform(xform);
```